# Unable to load the JSON data in Javascript which is to be printed on console

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, d3.js

I am trying to print the JSON data on console log

Here my intention is to print the json data in console which is present in relevence.json file

But it is not working,please help me this

In my jsp file

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/donut.js"></script>
```

and my donut.js is

```
function loadJSON(callback) {

var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
xobj.open('GET', 'relevancy.json', true);
xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {

        // .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in async mode so use a callback
        callback(xobj.responseText);

    }
}
xobj.send(null);
}

// Call to function with anonymous callback
loadJSON(function(response) {
    // Do Something with the response e.g.
    jsonresponse = JSON.parse(response);

    // Assuming json data is wrapped in square brackets as Drew suggests
   console.log(jsonresponse[0].relevance);
});
```

my json file is

```
[
 {"created_by":null, 
   "created_date":null,
  "last_update_date":null,
   "relevance":100,
   "search_keyword":"unable login",
   "solution_description":"unable to login into clarity application",
   "solution_id":1,
   "technology":"Claims"
   }
]
```

Nothing is printed on the console

Comment: First off, your json-file is malformed. You can see that on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Comment: Do you ever get in the onreadystatechange function?

Comment: Can you add an xobj.onerror method and check if you get there?

Comment: Why are you just using `d3.json`?

Comment: @Mark I am using it as per my requirement purpose as per remaining part of the project.Can u please help me with wher ei am getting wrong

Comment: Opps, sorry, I meant to say why **are you not** using [d3.json](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json)?  Writing your own `XMLHttpRequest` code seems like a strange way to go...

Comment: @Mark I am stuck in figuring out,can u please give me clue or can u give an sample implementation using d3.json

Comment: @RaghuRamMullapudi It's just `d3.json("relevancy.json", function(data){ console.log(data)});`.

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :**

- Verify `response` Object. Is it `JSON Object` or `JSON String`. If it is JSON String then you have to use `JSON.parse(response)`

```js
var jsonObj = [{
 "created_by": null,
 "created_date": null,
 "last_update_date": null,
 "relevance": 100,
 "search_keyword": "unable login",
 "solution_description": "unable to login into clarity application",
 "solution_id": 1,
 "technology": "Claims"
}];

console.log(jsonObj[0].relevance);
```

Comment: if we take the data in the same file like above its is working fine.but the real problem arises when we loading the data from the other file.Can u please help me with that@Rohit